# web.py not importing MySQLdb

Tags: python, web.py, mysql-python, sys.path

I'm working with web.py and for some reason I am getting the following error:

```
[Thu Sep 29 13:47:20 2011] [error] [client 64.8.210.120]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/web.py-0.36-py2.6.egg/web/db.py", line 975, in __init__
[Thu Sep 29 13:47:20 2011] [error] [client 64.8.210.120]     import MySQLdb as db
[Thu Sep 29 13:47:20 2011] [error] [client 64.8.210.120] ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

Here is my sys.path, in case that's the culprit? I see the.egg, though, so I don't know. Thoughts?

```
 ['', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Bravo-1.7.2-py2.6.egg', 
    '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Twisted-11.0.0-py2.6-linux-i686.egg',
     '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/construct-2.04-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/zope.interface-3.7.0-py2.6-linux-i686.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/web.py-0.36-py2.6.egg', 
'/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-linux-i686.egg', 
    '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.6.egg',
     '/usr/lib/python26.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', 
    '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages',
     '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL']
```

Here are the contents of the 2.6 site-packages directory:

```
[root@xxxx ~]# locate *.egg
/root/MySQL-python-1.2.3/dist/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-linux-i686.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/errorhandler-1.1.1-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/xlrd-0.7.1-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/xlutils-1.4.1-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/xlutils-1.4.1-py2.5.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/xlwt-0.7.2-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Bravo-1.7.2-py2.6.egg
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-linux-i686.egg
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Twisted-11.0.0-py2.6-linux-i686.egg
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/construct-2.04-py2.6.egg
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.6.egg
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/web.py-0.36-py2.6.egg
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/zope.interface-3.7.0-py2.6-linux-i686.egg
```

If I open python (either 2.4 or 2.6), I am able to `import MySQLdb` with no problem.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of your bashrc (usually in `/etc/bashrc`) file put this (or just update the `PYTHONPATH` env variable to include `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages`):

```
if [ $PYTHONPATH ]
then
    export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.6/:/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
else
    export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.6/:/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
fi
```

Or, for the specific user that is running the script, put the above in `/home/[USER_RUNNING_SCRIPT]/.bashrc`.

Then source the file:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
# or
# source /etc/bashrc
```

Comment: You never need to add the system package directories.

Comment: Actually, this worked. It's having another permissions issue now, but those are usually much easier to solve. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it fixed up Tom!  @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, the user running the script probably has an empty PYTHONPATH or has changed it somehow.

Comment: @chown: Except that the `site` module adds those directories, not `$PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 0):

You can download mysqldb at : http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a simple page to show the sys.path as it exists from within the web server execution environment.  Not sure if that's what you're showing when you show your sys.path in your question or if you ran that interactively from your login.  Chances are the userid that the http server is running under has a different environment set up from what you have as a regular user.